# Universal kriging has a long processing time compared to other kriging methods - R

Tags: r, geospatial, kriging, gstat, spatial-interpolation

I have a dataset `data_sp` with 132 observations containing 9 predictors and 1 response variable. I perform a twenty-fold cross validation, using ordinary kriging and universal kriging. The raster `grid100` on which I do my kriging, contains 61124 features (i.e. cells). For universal kriging, the 9 predictors related to the raster, are also included to account for trends.  Applying a twenty-fold cross validation on ordinary kriging yields quick results, however, applying a twenty-fold cross validation takes me a minimum of 5 hours (even with parallel kriging as suggested [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/237672/how-to-achieve-parallel-kriging-in-r-to-speed-up-the-process)). There are other posts that discuss the slowness of universal kriging ([e.g. here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41067597/how-slow-is-too-slow-when-kriging-with-gstat-in-r)) and one of the answers points to the number of observations used. In my case, 132 observations should not impact the processing time that much, I assume.

My question:
What explains the slow processing that relates to universal kriging and how can I speed this process up, despite parallel kriging?

Code (universal kriging):

```
library(sp) # processing spatial vector data - the way gstat needs it
library(raster) # processing spatial raster data.
library(Metrics) #MAE, R2, RMSE
library('parallel') #parallel kriging
library(gstat)   # The most popular R-Package for Kriging 
library(automap) # Automatize some (or all) parts of the gstat-workflow 

### === Cross Validation === ###

#examine and compare model performances between the Random Effects Model and Linear Model via 20-fold cross-validation - 75% training; 25% testing

#create empty lists where results per round can be stored to
MAE_model = c() #Mean Absolute Error - will be used later to calculate MAE statistics
RMSE_model = c() #Root Mean Square Error - will be used later to calculate RMSE statistics
R2_model = c() - will be used later to calculate R2 statistics

#twenty seeds - encouraging reproducability
Seeds = list(1, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35, 40, 45, 50, 55, 60, 65, 70, 75, 80 , 85, 90, 95)
Rounds = seq(1,length(Seeds),1)


i = 1
j = 1
## CREATE TRAIN- AND TEST DATASETS
while(i <= length(Seeds)){
  print(Rounds[[j]]) #confirm start of next element
  print(i) #confirm start of next element in list Seeds
  set.seed(Seeds[[i]])
  dataset = sort(sample(nrow(data_sp), nrow(data_sp)*.75)) #training = 75% (0.75)
  
  train <- data_sp[dataset,]
  test <- data_sp[-dataset,]
  
  
  variogram_uk = autofitVariogram(Lopend_gemiddelde ~ 1 + nightlight_450 + nightlight_4950 + population_3000 + road_class_1_5000 + road_class_2_1000 + road_class_2_5000 + road_class_3_100 + road_class_3_300 + trafBuf50, input_data = train)
  autofit_params_uk <- variogram_uk$var_model
  
  
  #PARALLEL

  
  # Calculate the number of cores
  no_cores <- detectCores() - 1
  
  # Initiate cluster (after loading all the necessary object to R environment: data_sp, grid100, autofit_params_uk)
  cl <- makeCluster(no_cores)
  
  parts <- split(x = 1:length(grid100), f = 1:no_cores)
  
  clusterExport(cl = cl, varlist = c("train", "grid100", "autofit_params_uk", "parts"), envir = .GlobalEnv)
  clusterEvalQ(cl = cl, expr = c(library('sp'), library('gstat')))
  
  
  #universal kriging
  system.time(parallelX <- parLapply(cl = cl, X = 1:no_cores, fun = function(x) krige(formula = Lopend_gemiddelde ~ 1 + nightlight_450 + nightlight_4950 + population_3000 + road_class_1_5000 + road_class_2_1000 + road_class_2_5000 + road_class_3_100 + road_class_3_300 + trafBuf50, locations = train, newdata = grid100[parts[[x]],], model = autofit_params_uk)))
  
  stopCluster(cl)
  
  # Merge all the predictions    
  mergeParallelX <- maptools::spRbind(parallelX[[1]], parallelX[[2]])
  mergeParallelX <- maptools::spRbind(mergeParallelX, parallelX[[3]])
  mergeParallelX <- maptools::spRbind(mergeParallelX, parallelX[[4]])
  mergeParallelX <- maptools::spRbind(mergeParallelX, parallelX[[5]])
  mergeParallelX <- maptools::spRbind(mergeParallelX, parallelX[[6]])
  mergeParallelX <- maptools::spRbind(mergeParallelX, parallelX[[7]])
  mergeParallelX <- maptools::spRbind(mergeParallelX, parallelX[[8]])
  mergeParallelX <- maptools::spRbind(mergeParallelX, parallelX[[9]])
  mergeParallelX <- maptools::spRbind(mergeParallelX, parallelX[[10]])
  mergeParallelX <- maptools::spRbind(mergeParallelX, parallelX[[11]])
  mergeParallelX <- maptools::spRbind(mergeParallelX, parallelX[[12]])
  mergeParallelX <- maptools::spRbind(mergeParallelX, parallelX[[13]])
  mergeParallelX <- maptools::spRbind(mergeParallelX, parallelX[[14]])
  mergeParallelX <- maptools::spRbind(mergeParallelX, parallelX[[15]])
  
  
  # Create SpatialPixelsDataFrame from mergeParallelX
  mergeParallelX <- SpatialPixelsDataFrame(points = mergeParallelX, data = mergeParallelX@data)
  
  # Plot mergeParallelX    
  spplot(mergeParallelX["var1.pred"], main = "universal kriging predictions")
  
  #convert to raster
  raster_uk <- raster(mergeParallelX["var1.pred"])
  #examine
  plot(raster_uk)
  
  
  #make predictions on the testing dataset, using the trained model
  
  #narrow data
  test <- test[,c("Lopend_gemiddelde", "spachar", "nightlight_450", "nightlight_4950",  "population_3000" , "road_class_1_5000", "road_class_2_1000" , "road_class_2_5000","road_class_3_100", "road_class_3_300", "trafBuf50")]
  
  
  
  #spatially join predicted values by trained model with corresponding kriged residuals.
  predicted_model = raster::extract(raster_uk, test, sp=T) #sp = T: keep all data
  
  
  predicted_model <- predicted_model %>% rename(predicted = "var1.pred")
  
  #rename variable
  Evaluation_UK_train <- predicted_model
  
  ## == model performance (MAE) == ##
  
  Evaluation_UK_train$MAE_model = mae(Evaluation_UK_train$Lopend_gemiddelde, Evaluation_UK_train$predicted)
  
  
  #store results to variable that will be assigned to list
  MAE_model_round = Evaluation_UK_train$MAE_model
  
  
  #store results to list that was defined before loop.
  MAE_model[[paste0("Round ", j)]] <- MAE_model_round #assign the errors for each round to a group "Round x" where x varies per round 
  
  
  ## == model performance (RMSE) == ##
  
  #2. R SQUARED error metric -- Coefficient of Determination
  RSQUARE = function(y_actual,y_predict){
    cor(y_actual,y_predict)^2}
  
  Evaluation_UK_train$R2_model = RSQUARE(Evaluation_UK_train$Lopend_gemiddelde,Evaluation_UK_train$predicted)
  
  
  #store results to variable that will be assigned to list
  R2_model_round = Evaluation_UK_train$R2_model
  
  
  #store results to list that was defined before loop.
  R2_model[[paste0("Round ", j)]] <- R2_model_round #assign the errors for each round to a group "Round x" where x varies per round 
  
  
  ## == model performance (RMSE) == ##
 
  
  Evaluation_UK_train$RMSE_model = rmse(Evaluation_UK_train$Lopend_gemiddelde, Evaluation_UK_train$predicted)
  
  
  #store results to variable that will be assigned to list
  RMSE_model_round = Evaluation_UK_train$RMSE_model
  
  
  #store results to list that was defined before loop.
  RMSE_model[[paste0("Round ", j)]] <- RMSE_model_round #assign the errors for each round to a group "Round x" where x varies per round 
  
  
  
  #next round
  i = i+1
  j = j+1
  
}
```